# Create a frame for a title page

Tags: titles, framed

I have already created my title page with `\begin{titlepage}` command and I want to put a single boxed frame around it. I've tried `fbox`, `framebox`, `makebox` and a few others and none of them put the frame around the whole page. The only package that worked was `fancybox` with

```
\thisfancyput(3.15in,-4.5in){%
\setlength{\unitlength}{2.65cm}\fancyoval}%(7,9.7)}%
```

but the problem is I don't want an oval box. I only need a single page border like Word does. My title page is this:

```
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}

% Upper part of the page    
\textsc{\LARGE University}\\[2.5cm]

\textsc{\Large Project}\\[3cm]

% Title
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Title}\\[0.4cm]

\HRule \\[4cm]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}   
\begin{flushleft} \large 
\emph{Author:}\\
name \textsc{name}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
name \textsc{name}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

% Bottom of the page
{\large \today}

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: I have no idea what Word does.  Can you post an image?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

May be like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[line width = 4pt] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-1in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-1in,1in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}

% Upper part of the page
\textsc{\LARGE University}\\[2.5cm]

\textsc{\Large Project}\\[3cm]

% Title
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Title}\\[0.4cm]

\HRule \\[4cm]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
name \textsc{name}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
name \textsc{name}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

% Bottom of the page
{\large \today}

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm Harish! I just had to adjust the margins of tickz a bit (0.5 in) cause my title was out of the frame

Comment: How can we extend this to every page of the document?