# Wrong effect with border of title page

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

I want this effect:

[image: true effect]

But I have this wrong effect:

[image: wrong effect]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paper

\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying

\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\setstretch{1.3} % Line spacing of 1.3

% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for one-sided printing
\fancyhead{} % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage} % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{} % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy} % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % New command to make the lines in the title page

% PDF meta-data
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\ttitle}}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=3pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);
    \draw [xshift=4mm,dashed,line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (.5cm,-.5cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-.5cm,.5cm) $);
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1.5cm,-1.5cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.5cm,1.5cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}

\textsc{\LARGE \univname}\\[1.5cm] % University name
\textsc{\Large Doctoral Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle}\\[0.4cm] % Thesis title
\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{\authornames} % Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
\href{http://www.jamessmith.com}{\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link  
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]

\large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfilment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
\textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
\groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name

{\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date
%\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it

\vfill
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

And this is my class file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Thesis LaTeX Template - THESIS CLASS FILE
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.latextemplates.com
%
% This class file defines the structure and design of the template. 
%
% There is one part of this file that needs to be filled out - the variables
% dictating the document particulars such as the author name, university
% name, etc. You will find these in the commented "DOCUMENT VARIABLES"
% section below.
%
% The other two easily-editable sections are the margin sizes and abstract.
% These have both been commented for easy editing. Advanced LaTeX
% users will have no trouble editing the rest of the document to their liking.
%
% Original header:
%% This is file `Thesis.cls', based on 'ECSthesis.cls', by Steve R. Gunn
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% Created by Steve R. Gunn, modified by Sunil Patel: www.sunilpatel.co.uk
%% Further modified by www.latextemplates.com
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
              [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

\newcommand\Declaration[1]{
\btypeout{Declaration of Authorship}
\addtotoc{Declaration of Authorship}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
%\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\huge\bf Declaration of Authorship\par}\end{center}
%\vskip 60\p@
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null
%\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\year}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\usepackage{vmargin}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allows the use of international characters (e.g. Umlauts)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
\setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\lstset{captionpos=b,
        frame=tb,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keepspaces=true}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
        language=Matlab,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
   \let\\\space
}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\thesistitle}[1]{\def\ttitle{#1}}
\newcommand*{\examiner}[1]{\def\examname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\def\degreename{#1}}
\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\def\authornames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\addresses}[1]{\def\addressnames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\university}[1]{\def\univname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\UNIVERSITY}[1]{\def\UNIVNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\deptname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\DEPARTMENT}[1]{\def\DEPTNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\group}[1]{\def\groupname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\GROUP}[1]{\def\GROUPNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\FACULTY}[1]{\def\FACNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\subjectname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\def\keywordnames{#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENT VARIABLES
%   Fill in the lines below to update the thesis template
%   If you wish to cite each of the variables defined below, look at the
%   section above for the citation command e.g. \examiner{} below is
%   defined as \examname above so you cite it as \examname
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{Thesis Title} % Your thesis title - this is used in the title and abstract
%-------------------------------------------------  
\supervisor{Dr. James \textsc{Smith}} % You supervisor's name - this is used in the title page
%-------------------------------------------------   
\examiner{} % Your examiner's name - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \examname if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name - this is currently used in the title page and abstract
%-------------------------------------------------   
\authors{John \textsc{Smith}} % Your name - this is used in the title page and abstract
%-------------------------------------------------   
\addresses{} % Your address - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \addressnames if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\subject{} % Your subject area - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \subjectname if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \keywordnames if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\university{\texorpdfstring{\href{http://www.university.com} % Your university's URL
                {University Name}} % Your university's name - this is currently used in the title page
                {University Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------   
\UNIVERSITY{\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your university's URL
                {UNIVERSITY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your university's name in capitals - this is currently used in the abstract page
                {UNIVERSITY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\department{\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your department's URL
                {Department or School Name}} % Your department's name - used in the title page and abstract
                {Department or School Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\DEPARTMENT{\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your department's URL
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your department's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \DEPTNAME if you want it
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\group{\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your research group's URL
                {Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name - this is currently used in the title page 
                {Research Group Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\GROUP{\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your research group's URL
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your research group's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \GROUPNAME if you want it
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\faculty{\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your faculty's URL
                {Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name - this is currently used in the abstract page
                {Faculty Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\FACULTY{\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your faculty's URL
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your faculty's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \FACNAME if you want it
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

% The default title page, this is not used in this www.latextemplates.com version            
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      \vfill
      {\huge \bf \@title \par}
      \vfill
      {\LARGE by \par}
      \smallskip
      {\LARGE \authornames \par}
      \vfill
      {\large A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the \par}
      {\large degree of \degreename \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large in the \par}
      {\large \facname \par}
      {\large \deptname \par} 
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\Large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
  \btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfil
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\normalsize \UNIVNAME \par} % University name in capitals
    \bigskip
    {\huge{\textit{Abstract}} \par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \facname \par} % Faculty name
    {\normalsize \deptname \par} % Department name
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \degreename\par} % Degree name
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize\bf \@title \par} % Thesis title
    \medskip
    {\normalsize by \authornames \par} % Author name
    \bigskip
  \end{center}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\addtotoc{Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
   \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
\btypeout{List of Figures}
\addtotoc{List of Figures}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{
\btypeout{List of Tables}
\addtotoc{List of Tables}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \@starttoc{lot}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
\btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listconstants{Physical Constants}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofconstants[2]{
\btypeout{\listconstants}
\addtotoc{\listconstants}
    \chapter*{\listconstants
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listconstants}{\MakeUppercase\listconstants}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
    \chapter*{\listnomenclature
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{
\btypeout{Acknowledgements}
\addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgements}} \par}\end{center}
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null

}
\newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
\btypeout{Dedicatory}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\Large \sl #1}\end{center}
\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
}
\renewcommand\backmatter{
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \addtotoc{\bibname}
  \btypeout{\bibname}
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\endinput
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I personally do not like to fetch code somewhere else ;-)

Comment: Is this question somehow related to `tikz-pgf` or why did you tag it accordingly?

Comment: @Werner, @Christian when I write this question I don't know how to indent four space quickly all my code to produce code block :(. And after comment of @Christian I know this shortcut `Ctrl + K`. Begin use Q&A site, I must learn many things :). Thank you!

Comment: @glider: Unrelated question: How are you able to have more than one @-notification in your comment?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Yes, I did. But still wrong effect :(

Comment: @Werner I don't know why when I write first comment it accept me write multiple @-noti, but now I can't :|

Comment: @HarishKumar: Oh, but when I try this examples: 

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129088/create-a-frame-for-a-title-page

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73611/multiple-border-around-page

It all work. But when add to my document with my class file it won't work :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an incompatibility between the package `vmargin` and the way TikZ computes the "current page" anchors.

One possible solution is to replace `vmargin` with `geometry`, which does not have this issue. You have to replace the following lines 70--84 in your `Thesis.cls`:

```
\usepackage{vmargin}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allows the use of international characters (e. → g. Umlauts)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
```

with:

```
%\usepackage{vmargin}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allows the use of international characters (e. → g. Umlauts)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[
    left   = 1.5in,
    top    = 0.6in,
    right  = 1.0in,
    bottom = 0.8in,
    headheight = 20pt,
    headsep    = 0.25in,
    footskip   = 9pt,
    footnotesep=0.3in
]{geometry}
```

After several compilations you get:

[image: titlepage]

Another solution, if you don't want or can't to modify your `.cls` file, is to correct the coordinates of the `current page` node, which are offset `1in` both in x and y. So, your frame has to be drawn like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=3pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm) + (1in,1in) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) + (1in, 1in) $);
    \draw [xshift=4mm,dashed,line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (.5cm,-.5cm) + (1in, 1in) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-.5cm,.5cm) + (1in, 1in) $);
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1.5cm,-1.5cm) + (1in, 1in) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.5cm,1.5cm) + (1in, 1in) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces the same result than the above image.

Comment: After seeing the picture, before reading your answer, I was certain to find `vmargin` in the code. The problem is that `vmargin` sets `\hoffset` and `\voffset` to zero, while LaTeX and TikZ expect them to be the default. As you  show, it's possible to remedy by adding somewhere `1in` to the coordinates. Anyhow, `vmargin` is incompatible with several other packages, notably `atbegshi` and those which depend on it.

Comment: @JLDiaz: Oh, awesome. It work :). But I don't know why `vmargin` is incompatible with `tikZ`? And why adding somewhere `1in` to the coordinates can solve this problem? Can you explain for me? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @glider, read above comment, by egreg :-)

Comment: @JLDiaz: I have read it several times, but it have many new terminology for me, so I do some Googling right now :)

Comment: @glider, in essence, tikz does some computations to determine which are the absolute coordinates of the page corners, to store them in the node named `current page`, but these computations assume that two TeX internal lengths called `\hoffset` and `\voffset` have their default value of `1in`. These lengths are added to all coordinates in the page, but `vmargin` changed their default value to `0in`, so all absolute coordinates computed by tikz are offset in that amount.

Comment: @JLDiaz: Wow, very clear explanation. Thank you! :)