# Making a border and hrule for title page

Tags: titles, border

I'd like to make a border around my coverpage as well as a horizontal line separating the title from the authors. When I attempt an `\HRule`, it always goes on a separate page to title page. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\settowidth{\thanksmarkwidth}{*}
\setlength{\thanksmargin}{-\thanksmarkwidth}}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue}

\predate{\begin{center}\placetitlepicture\large}
\postdate{\par\end{center}}


\newcommand{\titlepicture}[2][]{%
\renewcommand\placetitlepicture{%
\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\par\medskip
}%
}
\newcommand{\placetitlepicture}{} % initialization

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\title{\vspace{-2.0cm}\textbf{Analysis on the Impact and Effectiveness\\[0.5cm] of the BCEA Earning Threshold}}


\author{Morn\'e Oosthuizen \\[3ex] Christopher Rooney 
\titlepicture[scale=0.2]{DPRU.png}
\date{}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, there are an error on your code : Too many }'s in `\setlength{\thanksmargin}{-\thanksmarkwidth}}`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129088/create-a-frame-for-a-title-page) is for you.
You can find the border on titlepage and the separating line between title and author.

By the way, for the separating line, I try to insert `\vspace*{0.5cm}\hrule` at the end of title command in your code and it works for me.

For the box, you can also consider to use tikz package to directly "draw" your title page.